# How to change class name to my selection in html dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these input fields which serves what I need

```
<div class="tab" data-tab-name="height">Fridge Height:
    <input class="" type="checkbox" oninput="this.className = '65-66'">65 to 66 Inches
    <input class="" type="checkbox" oninput="this.className = '67-68'">67 to 68 Inches
</div>
```

Now how can I implement the same to below dropdown?

```
<select class="">
    <option value="15">15 Inches</option>
    <option value="16">16 Inches</option>
    <option value="17">17 Inches</option>
</select>
```

I want to change select class to the option I choose from dropdown

Comment: Why don't you just set the class on them statically?  I'm really confused why you are trying to do this with javascript.

Comment: Otherwise probably something like `<select onchange="this.className = this.value">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change select's class based on selected option's class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063504/change-selects-class-based-on-selected-options-class)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: `<select onchange="this.className = this.value">`

Thank you Taplar for the answer.